# cannot pass learnyounode: is the callback function used uncorrectly?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to solve the sixth problem of [learnyounode](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode) which needs a module file to print file list. Here are my two files:

The main file `program.js`:

```
var mymodule = require('./module.js');

mymodule(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], function(err, file){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(file);
});
```

The module file `module.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var fileExt;

module.exports = function(dir, ext, callback) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files){
        if(err){
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        files.forEach(function(file){
            fileExt = path.extname(file).substring(1);
            if(fileExt === ext){
                callback(null, file);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

But it throws an error:

```
processors[i].call(self, mode, function (err, pass) {               
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions state that you need to call `callback` only once, with an array containing of all the matching files. In your case, you are calling `callback` once for *every matching file*.

Comment: By the way, leaving aside learnyounode, can I use node.js like in my question in reality? or usually, callback function should be only called once?

Comment: It's conventional to have callbacks only called once - I think this is what most Node developers would expect when using the `err, callback` pattern.